# Gridview inside update panel not refreshing when click on button inside gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, updatepanel

I have a gridview which load data on dropdown OnSelectedIndexChanged change. The grid view is inside an update panel. Data loaded successfully. But when I click on the delete link button (Id="btnDelete") inside the update panel, the data is removed from the database but the grid view is not refreshing.I found the error in the console as,

```
ScriptResource.axd?d=DT3YJR8QaqV61-teuz0hgjs5-RCOey2-uDAyhszGAHbLjEcc31icIOPnrYipVEyQcXFMxnve0uP6xEvgOIC53vEC-feFnRyAEu_AKMP4G6e6S-L7bP5B3AYVhopxS7MPDYDXflFfsfy3B0lvfqyFKQ2&t=60b7ac5d:940 Uncaught Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.
    at Function.Error$create [as create] (ScriptResource.axd?d=yeSNAJTOPtPimTGCAo3LlQGMjf69gb9mP9Cg5L8cFQrpj29YLswnMWucwR38cSJVgaRydbsSurxoNqaEDGskNdXYd0Esj7Ur7el2ofn5TPuvlHvoElCZjnStXN2vl-sz0&t=60b7ac5d:847)
    at PageRequestManager$_createPageRequestManagerParserError [as _createPageRequestManagerParserError] (ScriptResource.axd?d=DT3YJR8QaqV61-teuz0hgjs5-RCOey2-uDAyhszGAHbLjEcc31icIOPnrYipVEyQcXFMxnve0uP6xEvgOIC53vEC-feFnRyAEu_AKMP4G6e6S-L7bP5B3AYVhopxS7MPDYDXflFfsfy3B0lvfqyFKQ2&t=60b7ac5d:776)
    at PageRequestManager$_parseDelta [as _parseDelta] (ScriptResource.axd?d=DT3YJR8QaqV61-teuz0hgjs5-RCOey2-uDAyhszGAHbLjEcc31icIOPnrYipVEyQcXFMxnve0uP6xEvgOIC53vEC-feFnRyAEu_AKMP4G6e6S-L7bP5B3AYVhopxS7MPDYDXflFfsfy3B0lvfqyFKQ2&t=60b7ac5d:1554)
    at PageRequestManager$_onFormSubmitCompleted [as _onFormSubmitCompleted] (ScriptResource.axd?d=DT3YJR8QaqV61-teuz0hgjs5-RCOey2-uDAyhszGAHbLjEcc31icIOPnrYipVEyQcXFMxnve0uP6xEvgOIC53vEC-feFnRyAEu_AKMP4G6e6S-L7bP5B3AYVhopxS7MPDYDXflFfsfy3B0lvfqyFKQ2&t=60b7ac5d:1414)
    at Array.<anonymous> (ScriptResource.axd?d=yeSNAJTOPtPimTGCAo3LlQGMjf69gb9mP9Cg5L8cFQrpj29YLswnMWucwR38cSJVgaRydbsSurxoNqaEDGskNdXYd0Esj7Ur7el2ofn5TPuvlHvoElCZjnStXN2vl-sz0&t=60b7ac5d:628)
    at ScriptResource.axd?d=yeSNAJTOPtPimTGCAo3LlQGMjf69gb9mP9Cg5L8cFQrpj29YLswnMWucwR38cSJVgaRydbsSurxoNqaEDGskNdXYd0Esj7Ur7el2ofn5TPuvlHvoElCZjnStXN2vl-sz0&t=60b7ac5d:4338
    at raise (ScriptResource.axd?d=yeSNAJTOPtPimTGCAo3LlQGMjf69gb9mP9Cg5L8cFQrpj29YLswnMWucwR38cSJVgaRydbsSurxoNqaEDGskNdXYd0Esj7Ur7el2ofn5TPuvlHvoElCZjnStXN2vl-sz0&t=60b7ac5d:7429)
    at WebRequest$completed [as completed] (ScriptResource.axd?d=yeSNAJTOPtPimTGCAo3LlQGMjf69gb9mP9Cg5L8cFQrpj29YLswnMWucwR38cSJVgaRydbsSurxoNqaEDGskNdXYd0Esj7Ur7el2ofn5TPuvlHvoElCZjnStXN2vl-sz0&t=60b7ac5d:7433)
    at XMLHttpRequest.XMLHttpExecutor._onReadyStateChange (ScriptResource.axd?d=yeSNAJTOPtPimTGCAo3LlQGMjf69gb9mP9Cg5L8cFQrpj29YLswnMWucwR38cSJVgaRydbsSurxoNqaEDGskNdXYd0Esj7Ur7el2ofn5TPuvlHvoElCZjnStXN2vl-sz0&t=60b7ac5d:6857)
```

Aspx page

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="drpDiv" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
<p style="margin: 0 0 5px 0;"><b>Details</b></p>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataKeyNames="OP_AS_ID" class="table table-striped table-bordered "
AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="4" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging1" PageSize="15"
ShowFooter="True" EmptyDataText="No Data Found" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Inherit">
<PagerStyle CssClass="numericpageul" />
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Slno" HeaderStyle-Width="10px">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblSl" Text='<%# Container.DisplayIndex+1%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title" HeaderStyle-Width="400px">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblCoAssTitlempanyName" Text='<%# Eval("OP_AS_Title") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Date" Text='<%# Eval("OP_AS_Date","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'
    runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Submission Date" HeaderStyle-Width="150px">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="DateofSub" Text='<%# Eval("OP_AS_LastDate","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'
    runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Attachment" HeaderStyle-Width="150px">
<ItemTemplate>
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.OP_ASF_FilePath")%>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" CommandName="Edit" runat="server"> <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want delete?')) return false;" runat="server"> <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon
glyphicon-trash"></span></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Cs page

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        decimal id = (decimal)GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
        DataTable dtas = Assignment.AssignmentDelete(id);//OP_del_AssignmentDelete
        if (dtas.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath(dtas.Rows[0][0].ToString());
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
            if (file.Exists)//check file exsit or not
            {
                file.Delete();
            }
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Deleted Sucessfully')</script>");
        }
        GridReset();
        LoadGridView();


    }
 public void GridReset()
    {
        GridView1.Visible = true;GridView1.DataSource = null;
    }
 public void LoadGridView()
    {

        decimal GsId = 0;
        if (drpDiv.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            GsId = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            GsId = Convert.ToDecimal(drpDiv.Text);
        }
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from OP_Assignments  inner join OP_AssignmentFiles on OP_Assignments.OP_AS_ID = OP_AssignmentFiles.OP_AS_ID where OP_AS_Staffid='" + StaffId + "' and OP_GS_IdNo='" + GsId + "' and OP_AS_SubjId='" + Convert.ToInt32(drpSubject.Text) + "' and OP_AS_TypeId='" + Convert.ToInt32(drpAssignmentType.Text) + "' order by OP_Assignments.OP_AS_ID desc,OP_AS_Type asc", con);
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(datatable);
        for (int index = 0; index < datatable.Rows.Count; index++)
        {
            string fpath = datatable.Rows[index]["OP_ASF_FilePath"].ToString();
            if ((fpath == "") || (fpath == "nofile"))
            {
                datatable.Rows[index]["OP_ASF_FilePath"] = "";
            }
            else
                datatable.Rows[index]["OP_ASF_FilePath"] = "<a style='padding-left:50px' target=_blank  href = '" + datatable.Rows[index]["OP_ASF_FilePath"].ToString() + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip'></span></a>";
        }
        GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        GridView1.DataSource = datatable;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: could you try adding the delete method for the update panel. like triggers

Comment: @kbvishnu Sorry i didn't get you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `Response.Write` during an asynchronous postback. GridView1_RowDeleting contains `Response.Write`. It throws an exception.

Comment: Thank you. That was the mistake. Thanks a lot